# How do I create a login form in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a User model (with all validators and properties defined) and a UsersController. For the controller, I have a login action and a login.html.erb view file. How do I create a simple login form that validates the username and password?

Comment: Why do you want to *validate* a username and password upon login? The user can either login or he can't, what more validation is necessary?

Comment: I want to _authenticate_ the user and use the form helpers to display back any errors (form input element highlighting, etc.).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you take a look at using either Authlogic or Devise to do your login. You can find a number of tutorials that will help guide you through setting up either service. I like the Railscasts on the two subjects:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic

If you want to roll your own authentication, you can. Railscasts also provides a tutorial on doing that:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: It doesn't look like authlogic is being actively maintained. Last commit was 5 months ago. Devise's last commit was 8 hours ago. I'd definitely go with Devise